Kafka topic not created in KafkaContainer
I'm trying to create a topic in my KafkaContainer using .withEnv("KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS", "subs-topic:1:1") but topic not created
I have ContainersConfiguration class
@Configuration
public class ContainersConfiguration {
    public static final DockerImageName KAFKA_IMAGE_NAME = DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1");
    private final Network network = Network.newNetwork();

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public ZookeeperContainer zookeeperContainer(ZookeeperContainerConfiguration zookeeperContainerConfiguration) {
        return new ZookeeperContainer()
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withNetworkAliases(zookeeperContainerConfiguration.getHost());
    }


    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public KafkaContainer kafkaContainer(KafkaContainerConfiguration kafkaContainerConfiguration,
                                         ZookeeperContainer zookeeperContainer) {
        return new KafkaContainer(KAFKA_IMAGE_NAME)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withEnv("KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS", "subs-topic:1:1").withNetworkAliases(kafkaContainerConfiguration.getBootstrapHost()).withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(180))
                .withExternalZookeeper(zookeeperContainer.getNetworkAliases().get(0) + ":" + CLIENT_PORT);
    }
}

and KafkaContainerConfiguration class

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:services.properties")
@Getter
@Setter
public class KafkaContainerConfiguration {

    @NotNull
    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap.server.host}")
    private String bootstrapHost;

    @NotNull
    @Value("${kafka.data.topic}")
    private String dataTopic;

    @NotNull
    @Value("${kafka.notification.topic}")
    private String notificationTopic;

}

In service.properties I have the following:
kafka.data.topic=subs-topic
kafka.notification.topic=subs-topic-notifications
KafkaProducerConfigurationClass contains the following
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer(Properties kafkaProperties) {
        return new KafkaProducer<>(kafkaProperties);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public AdminClient kafkaAdminClient(Properties kafkaProperties) {
        return AdminClient.create(kafkaProperties);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public Properties kafkaProperties(KafkaContainer kafkaContainer) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileReader(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("kafka.producer.properties").getFile())));
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
        return properties;
    }

}

Why topic wasn't created? What should I do to create topic?
I tried to use
CreateTopicsResult result = admin.createTopics(
  Collections.singleton(newTopic)
);

but it didn't help

I'd recommend using the native KafkaContainer which does not need zookeeper https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/ and uses the official Docker image


using .withEnv("KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS"

Only wurstmeister/kafka supports the environment variable KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS, but this image is no longer maintained.

In service.properties I have the following: kafka.data.topic=subs-topic

Okay. That just defines a String in your config.
You need a @Bean NewTopic method to be ran. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/configuring-topics.html

You also don't really need TestContainers with Spring-Kafka
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/testing.html
And your properties should be loaded from Spring's own resource files
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ...
    producer:
       properties:
          ...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/messaging/kafka.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Unfortunately I can't use Spring-Kafka because it depends on Java17 but we use Java11. Instead of @Bean NewTopc I use AdminClient directly    `public CreateTopicsResult createNewTopic(KafkaContainerConfiguration kafkaContainerConfiguration, AdminClient admin) {
NewTopic newTopic=  new NewTopic(kafkaContainerConfiguration.getDataTopic(), 1, (short) 1);
CreateTopicsResult result = admin.createTopics(
Collections.singleton(newTopic)
    );
    return result;
}`


You could use a lower version that doesn't need Java 17
